# Regarding Least Angle Regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, self-study, correlation, regression-coefficients

This question is from the textbook [The Element of Statistical Learning](https://hastie.su.domains/Papers/ESLII.pdf) chapter 3.
Let me describe the meaning of each variable first.

---

$A_k$: the active set of variables in the $k$-th step.
$\beta_{A_k}$: the coefficient vector for these variables at the beginning of the $k$-th step ($k-1$ nonzero values, and the one just entered will be zero). 
$\hat{f}_k = X_{ A_k}\beta_{A_k}$: the LAR fit vector at the beginning of the $k$-th step. 
$r_k = y - \hat{f}_k$: the residual vector at the beginning of the $k$-th step. 
$\bar f_k = X_{ A_k}(X_{ A_k}^T  X_{ A_k})^{-1}X_{ A_k}^T y$: the projection of $y$ on $C(X_{ A_k})$. 
$u_k = \bar f_k - \hat{f}_k$: the new fit direction (called the LAR direction).
Note that $X_{ A_k} (X_{ A_k}^T X_{ A_k})^{-1}X_{ A_k}^T r_k = u_k$.
(Let $\delta_k = (X_{ A_k}^T X_{ A_k})^{-1}X_{ A_k}^T r_k$.) 
$\hat{f}_k(\alpha) = \hat{f}_k + \alpha \cdot u_k = X_{ A_k} (\beta_{A_k} + \alpha \cdot \delta_k) = X_{ A_k}\beta_{A_k}(\alpha)$ 
$r_k(\alpha) = y - \hat{f}_k(\alpha) = r_k - \alpha \cdot u_k$.

---

My goal is to show the following statement;

> the absolute correlation between $r_k(\alpha) = r_k - \alpha u_k$ and each of the predictors in $A_k$ are all equal for all $\alpha \in (0,1)$, and the correlation is decreasing as $\alpha \to 1$.

In exercise 3.23, we have shown that (for $X = [x_1 ... x_k]$ I guess, $\hat \beta$ the least-squares coefficient of y on X, and $u(\alpha) =  \alpha X \hat \beta$)
$$\frac{1}{N} \vert \langle x_j, y - u(\alpha)\rangle \vert = \lambda (1-\alpha), $$

and the correlations are all equal as follows (RSS : residual sum of square);
$$ \lambda(\alpha) = \frac{1 - \alpha}{\sqrt{(1 - \alpha)^2 + \frac{\alpha (2-\alpha)}{N}\text{RSS}} }\lambda $$

However, the above exercise used $y - u(\alpha)$ not $r_k - \alpha u_k$, so it seems quite tough to induce the correlation between $r_k - \alpha u_k$ and each $x_j$. If possible, I want to associate the above results with my question, which isn't clear for now.

Any hint regarding this question, or other uncertain points on my question would be grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\aset}{\mathcal{A}_k}$
What you need to show is that $|\operatorname{Corr}(x_j, r_k(\alpha) - \alpha u_k)| = \frac{|\langle x_j, r_k - \alpha u_k\rangle|}{\|r_k - \alpha u_k\|}$ are identical for all $j \in \mathcal{A}_k$. Since the denominator does not depend on $j$, it suffices to show $|\langle x_j, r_k - \alpha u_k\rangle|$ are identical for all $j$.

To this end, note
\begin{align*}
& \langle x_j, u_k \rangle \\
=& \langle x_j, X_{\aset}\delta_k \rangle \\
=& \langle x_j, X_{\aset}(X_{\aset}^TX_{\aset})^{-1}X_{\aset}^Tr_k \rangle \\
=& \langle r_k, X_{\aset}(X_{\aset}^TX_{\aset})^{-1}X_{\aset}^Tx_j \rangle \\
=& \langle r_k, x_j \rangle.
\end{align*}

It therefore follows that $|\langle x_j, r_k - \alpha u_k\rangle| = (1 - \alpha)|\langle x_j, r_k\rangle|$, which by the LAR algorithm design have to be identical for $j \in \aset$ (i.e., Step 4 in Algorithm 3.2).